# Django Mocking framework patch

Tags: django, mocking, return-value, patch

While unit testing when I write a patch with .return_value, how can I assign more than one return_value? I want to test cases where the 'get_info' returns a number or string

```
@patch('Sprint.get_info')
def def_1(self, get_info):
    get_week_info.return_value = [10]
```

Comment: That sounds like 2 separate tests to me. Can you show what `get_info` is supposed to do and explains what's `def_1`?

Answer (score 1):

Patched methods can reset their state using the `my_mock_name.reset_mock()` method, then you can asign another return value, and continue testing over that mock object.

Since you don't provide any details about your `get_info` method, I've done this only for ilustration:

Supposing your module structure is as follows:

```
.
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── utils.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_me.py
```

**utils.py**

```
class Sprint(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_info(key):
        """
        Return the string representation for the key specified if the
        key is a number or the numeric value if key is an string
        """
        NUMBERS_LOOKUP = {'one': 1, 'ten': 10, 'five': 5, 5: 'five', 10: 'ten'}
        print 'a real call with "%s" as param' % key
        return NUMBERS_LOOKUP[key]
```

**test_me.py**

```
from nose.tools import *
from mock import patch
from unittest import TestCase

from mypackage.utils import Sprint


class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_get_info(self):
        """ A normal test """
        ret_value = Sprint.get_info('five')
        assert_equal(ret_value, 5)

    @patch.object(Sprint, 'get_info')
    def test_mocked_get_info(self, get_info_mock):
        """ A mocked test """
        get_info_mock.return_value = 5
        ret_value = Sprint.get_info('five')
        get_info_mock.assert_called_once_with('five')
        assert_equal(ret_value, 5)

        # reset mock object
        get_info_mock.reset_mock()
        get_info_mock.return_value = 'ten'
        ret_value = Sprint.get_info(10)

        get_info_mock.assert_called_once_with(10)
        assert_equal(ret_value, 'ten')
```

Here I'm using the nose module, so to run your tests you can use:

```
$ nosetests -s -v
A normal test ... a real call with "five" as param
ok
A mocked test ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.131s

OK
```

Notice the difference between the mocked and the normal test: in the first, the `get_info` is called.

Comment: Ohh it's a django issue. So, just use the `from django.test import TestCase` instead of the `from unittest import TestCase` and run using `python manage.py test`.